# Statically link devmapper when using CGO

Tags: go, ld, cgo, podman

I'm building a go 1.20 program that use [podman bindings](https://github.com/containers/podman/tree/main/pkg/bindings) (v4), one of its dependencies [require CGO](https://github.com/containers/image/issues/1634).

### Dynamically build & LD

Dynamically building the project works on alpine linux (golang:1.20-alpine), `ld` returns the following:

```
    /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f741c064000)
    libgpgme.so.11 => /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11 (0x7f741c01f000)
    libdevmapper.so.1.02 => /lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02 (0x7f741bfd4000)
    libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f741c064000)
    libassuan.so.0 => /usr/lib/libassuan.so.0 (0x7f741bfc1000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x7f741bfa0000)
```

The command I used is `CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o myprog ./cmd/cli/main.go`

### Trying statically build

But when I try to statically build (for use in a scratch container) with `go build -ldflags '-linkmode external -w -extldflags "-static"' -o myprog ./cmd/cli/main.go` I have this error:

```
/app # go build -ldflags '-linkmode external -w -extldflags "-static" ' -o myprog ./cmd/cli/main.go
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -ldevmapper: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### Dependencies installation

But It's installed along with other dependencies previously in the container:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc musl-dev lvm2-dev gpgme-dev btrfs-progs-dev
```

### What I've tried

I tried building from the ubuntu-based tag for go (golang:1.20), but same it can't find devmapper.
Explicitly setting to CGO_ENABLED to 0 or 1 don't change anything when trying to build statically.

I passed `-v` to go build to know how it's linking, here is the result:

```
/app # CC=gcc go build -ldflags '-linkmode external -w -extldflags "-static" -v' -o myprog ./cmd/cli/main.go
# command-line-arguments
HEADER = -H5 -T0x401000 -R0x1000
host link: "gcc" "-m64" "-o" "/tmp/go-build2898353667/b001/exe/a.out" "-static" "-Wl,--compress-debug-sections=zlib" "/tmp/go-link-3857943538/go.o" "/tmp/go-link-3857943538/000000.o" [...] "/tmp/go-link-3857943538/000053.o" "-O2" "-g" "-lresolv" "-O2" "-g" "-O2" "-g" "-lpthread" "-O2" "-g" "-O2" "-g" "-O2" "-g" "-ldl" "-O2" "-g" "-O2" "-g" "-lgpgme" "-O2" "-g" "-O2" "-g" "-L/lib" "-ldevmapper" "-O2" "-g" "-O2" "-g" "-O2" "-g" "-no-pie" "-static"
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -ldevmapper: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`libdevmapper` is in several location, including in `/lib` (as seen in the linker) at `/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02`

### Reproduce

main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/containers/podman/v2/pkg/bindings"
    "github.com/containers/podman/v2/pkg/bindings/images"
)

func main() {
    // Get Podman socket location
    sock_dir := os.Getenv("XDG_RUNTIME_DIR")
    socket := "unix:" + sock_dir + "/podman/podman.sock"

    // Connect to Podman socket
    ctx, err := bindings.NewConnection(context.Background(), socket)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // list images
    imgs, err := images.List(ctx, nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, img := range imgs {
        fmt.Printf("Names: %#v\n", img.Names)
    }
}
```

Containerfile (or Dockerfile):

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 docker.io/library/golang:1.20-alpine AS builder

RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc musl-dev lvm2-dev gpgme-dev btrfs-progs-dev

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

# Dont work
RUN go build -ldflags '-linkmode external -w -extldflags "-static" ' -o myprog ./main.go

# this works, but dynamically linked
# RUN go build -o myprog ./main.go
```

Then run:

```bash
go init sof-75459376
go mod tidy
# fail
podman build -t sof/75459376:latest .
```